# How to index into an object of class ClassificationSVM?

Tags: matlab

Following piece of code:

```
for i = 1:length(tempclasses)
    for j=i+1:length(tempclasses)
        ind1=find(strcmp([classes.class1],tempclasses(i)));
        ind2=find(strcmp([classes.class2],tempclasses(j)));
        ind=intersect(ind1,ind2);
        tmp=predict(SVMModel(ind).svm, histr);
        ind=find(strcmp({t.ind}, tmp));
        t(ind).fit=t(ind).fit+1;
    end
end
```

gives error:

> Error using classreg.learning.internal.DisallowVectorOps/subsref (line 16)
>   You cannot index into an object of class ClassificationSVM using () indexing.

Is there any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: You need to create a minimal working example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise it is not easy to help

Answer (score 0):

`i` should stop at `length(tempclasses)-1` instead of `length(tempclasses)`

Otherwise `j` will start at `i+1` wich is bigger than `length(tempclasses)` which will not assign a value to `j`